# how to set a function parameter like a list

Tags: postgresql

I created a function like the following one,

```
    DROP FUNCTION if exists test_list_parameter();
    CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test_list_parameter(???)
    returns setof test
    as
    $$
        select * from test
        where test.id in ($1);
    $$
    language sql
```

**how to set it for querying many ids at the same time?**

like the following code,
we need to set the parameter when id more than one, which like (1,2,3,4...) in where clause.
thanks for your help.

Comment: You can pass an `integer[]` (array of integers).

Comment: thanks @LaurenzAlbe
as you said, 
I have tried the method, but test.id is not that type, so it's an error.

Comment: Well, then tell us what type it is, and what exact problems you encounter in your attempt to implement this.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
like the answer below, the error is because I don't know the use of ANY.
thank you too, I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an array of the datatype that of the id. If it's integer, pass a `int[]` . If it's text, use `text[]` etc. Also, use `ANY` instead of `IN`

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test_list_parameter( idlist int [])
returns setof test
as
$$
    select * from test
    where test.id = ANY(idlist);
$$
language sql
```

Call it as

```
select * from test_list_parameter(ARRAY[1,3]);
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8ff9499fcd7bdd0942dcad392692b358)

Comment: thank you so much, I have solved my problem, I think the point is ANY(), I don't know its use before.